# C#(Rellenar Modal Bootstrap con funcion Ajax)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

```
public IActionResult GetAssetsTree(AssetDataModel Parent_ID, AuditIdRow row,string workspaceId){
     _assetService.CollectionName = workspaceId;
     _assetService.ParentId = workspaceId;
     return(Json(CreateTree(null,null)));
}
```

CreateTree me llama a un metodo privado

```
private AuditIdRow CreateTree(AssetDataModel Parent, AuditIdRow row){
return row;
}
```

Clase AuditIdRow

```
 public class AuditIdRow : BaseModel
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public bool IsGroup{get;set;}
        public List<AuditIdRow> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Vista html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-container-root" tabindex="1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4>Selecciona tu código de acción para trabajar</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="list-group" id="TreeGroups" role="tablist">
                    //Aqui es donde quiero cargar los datos
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Funcion javascript para cargar el modal:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {                
        $.get("GetAssetsTree") // llamo al método para que me devuelva los datos 
        .done(function (data){
            $.each(data,function(index,obj){
                $("#TreeGroups").append('<option value="'+obj.Name+'">'+obj.row.+'</option>');
            });
        })
        .fail(function(data){
            alert(data);
        } )
    });   
</script>
```

Quiero rellenar el modal con los datos que me vienen del método getAssetTree, donde quiero que me muestre primero el nombre de AuditIdRow, y dentro de él que me muestre la lista de children para hacer una vista TreeView dentro del modal.

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es estructurar lo que quieres que tenga el modal, que el ajax lo reciba como respuesta y lo agregue al modal al abrirlo

Answer (score 0):

Y cual es el fallo que tienes? Te llegan bien los datos del ajax? si es así veo que usas un foreach que en principio anida los datos bien al div TreeGroups,
lo que no entiendo es porque los pegas como option si no es un select.